# How to get next three months in oracle using sysdate

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have an sql server query that return current and next 3 months

```
SELECT CAST(DATENAME(month, getdate() )               as VARCHAR(3))  
     , CAST(DATENAME(month, dateadd(mm,1,getdate()) ) as VARCHAR(3))
     , CAST(DATENAME(month, dateadd(mm,2,getdate()) ) as VARCHAR(3))
     , CAST(DATENAME(month, dateadd(mm,3,getdate()) ) as VARCHAR(3))
```

How i can modify this to equivalent oracle query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`TO_CHAR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129) can be used to convert a date into a character. To get the current month in the 3 character format you can use the [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) `MON` when using TO_CHAR(). The data returned follows your capitalisation of the format model.

For instance:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'mon')
  2       , to_char(sysdate, 'MON')
  3    from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSD TO_CHAR(SYSD
------------ ------------
mar          MAR
```

The function [`ADD_MONTHHS()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions011.htm#SQLRF00603) can be used to add a month to a date:

```
SQL> select to_char(add_months(sysdate, 1), 'MON')
  2    from dual;

TO_CHAR(ADD_
------------
APR
```

You will be able to extend this to convert your entire query.

Comment: Is from clause is required?

Comment: Yes @Warrior, you must always use this in Oracle.

Comment: DUAL @Warrior?  Sort of, it's a special table to enable you to have a known result, as you would in SQL Server without a FROM clause. See the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datadict.htm#CNCPT1219

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Month'), 
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), 'Month'), 
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 2), 'Month'), 
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 3), 'Month')  
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'Month'),
to_char(ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE, 1 ), 'Month'),
to_char(ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE, 2 ), 'Month'),
to_char(ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE, 3 ), 'Month')



from dual
```